# mysql not updating all rows in tablw

Tags: mysql

My form presents all (85) records in table for possible update.
Update block:

```
            $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id ASC";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);

            // Count table rows
            $size=mysql_num_rows($result);

            $i = 0;
            while ($i < $size) {
                $name  = $_POST['name'][$i];
                $phone = $_POST['phone'][$i];
                $email = $_POST['email'][$i];
                $jan1  = $_POST['jan1'][$i];
                .
                .
                $dues1  = $_POST['dues1'][$i];
                .
                .
                $id    = $_POST['id'][$i];

                $query = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET name   = '$name',    phone  = '$phone',  email  = '$email',  jan1   = '$jan1',   feb2   = '$feb2',   mar3   = '$mar3',   apr4   = '$apr4',   may5   = '$may5',   jun6   = '$jun6',   jul7   = '$jul7',   aug8   = '$aug8',   sep9   = '$sep9',   oct10  = '$oct10',  nov11  = '$nov11',  dec12  = '$dec12',  dues1  = '$dues1',  dues2  = '$dues2',  dues3  = '$dues3',  dues4  = '$dues4',  dues5  = '$dues5',  dues6  = '$dues6',  dues7  = '$dues7',  dues8  = '$dues8',  dues9  = '$dues9',  dues10 = '$dues10', dues11 = '$dues11', dues12 = '$dues12' WHERE id = '$id'";

                //Just to see what's neing updated....
                echo "UPDATE $tbl_name SET name   = '$name',    phone  = '$phone',  email  = '$email',  jan1   = '$jan1',   feb2   = '$feb2',   mar3   = '$mar3',   apr4   = '$apr4',   may5   = '$may5',   jun6   = '$jun6',   jul7   = '$jul7',   aug8   = '$aug8',   sep9   = '$sep9',   oct10  = '$oct10',  nov11  = '$nov11',  dec12  = '$dec12',  dues1  = '$dues1',  dues2  = '$dues2',  dues3  = '$dues3',  dues4  = '$dues4',  dues5  = '$dues5',  dues6  = '$dues6',  dues7  = '$dues7',  dues8  = '$dues8',  dues9  = '$dues9',  dues10 = '$dues10', dues11 = '$dues11', dues12 = '$dues12' WHERE id = '$id'";
                    echo "<hr>";

                mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
                ++$i;
            }
            //header('Location: allselect.php');
            ?>
```

My echo shows good update up to record 57.  Record 58 is partially ok.  The rest (up to 85) NOTHING.
UPDATE rollcalltest SET name = '*****-Wise **', phone = 'XXX-XXX-XXXX',   email = '******@gmail.com', jan1 = '1', feb2 = '1', mar3 = '',  apr4 = '1', may5 = '1', jun6 = '1', jul7 = '',  aug8 = '',  sep9 = '',  oct10 = '', nov11 = '', dec12 = '', dues1 = '0',    dues2 = '0',    dues3 = '', dues4 = '', dues5 = '', dues6 = '', dues7 = '', dues8 = '', dues9 = '', dues10 = '',    dues11 = '',    dues12 = '' WHERE id = '58'
UPDATE rollcalltest SET name = '', phone = '',  email = '', jan1 = '',  feb2 = '',  mar3 = '',  apr4 = '',  may5 = '',  jun6 = '',  jul7 = '',  aug8 = '',  sep9 = '',  oct10 = '', nov11 = '', dec12 = '', dues1 = '', dues2 = '', dues3 = '', dues4 = '', dues5 = '', dues6 = '', dues7 = '', dues8 = '', dues9 = '', dues10 = '',    dues11 = '',    dues12 = '' WHERE id = ''

I am going crazy.  Ideas?

Comment: Double check on where clause? (How do you get your $id)

Comment: Does your post-data contain 85 arrays, your table contains 85 rows and the ids are numbered sequentially 1..85 with no gaps? Even If so, I'm not surprised you are going crazy! Your code should not rely on id numbers running sequentially (without gaps), particularly if they are auto-numbers (increment).

Comment: `echo $query` instead of building a separate (and possibly wrong) output. What do you get then? (Do you really have a table that has 48 columns of dues information, with a separate column for each month and the dues for that month? Find a tutorial on normalization somewhere, if you do.)

Comment: Thanks guys.  The table has 12 months of attendance record and 12 months of dues records.  From my code ($size=mysql_num_rows($result);), if I echo $size, it does show 85.

Comment: Slight progress.  I split this into 2 programs.  One updates attendance, the other dues.  The attendance table works perfectly, but the dues table now returns nothing after record 63.  Query is as before except now I am not selecting *.